# Turning a EasynetQ subscriber into an observable

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, reactive-programming, system.reactive, easynetq

I am using EasyNetQ as client library when using RabbitMQ. To create a subscriber one do like

```
bus.Subscribe<MyMessage>("my_subscription_id", msg => Console.WriteLine(msg.Text));
```

When an instance of MyMessage is published, EasyNetQ will call the delegate and print the message’s Text property to the console.

How do I turn this into an observable sequence? I have been looking at the `Observable.Create` and `Observable.Generate` methods but I cannot figure out how to bridge a RabbitMQ consumer and an observable sequence.

The `Subscribe` method returns an `IDisposable` so a solution should respect this such that the resource can be properly disposed.

I have noticed this [solution](https://github.com/mauriciogentile/EasyNetQ.Rx/blob/master/Source/EasyNetQ.Rx/ObservableBus.cs) but most people seem to advice against using `Subject` so I would like to find another solution.

Any hints or ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
var observable = Observable.Create<MyMessage>(o => 
    bus.Subscribe<MyMessage>("my_subscription_id", msg => o.OnNext(msg))
);
```

I don't have a problem with the way `Subject` is used in the referenced code: If `Subject` is a private (ideally read-only) field, only exposed as an `IObservable` then its impact is contained. However there's other problems with the code at that referenced link:

- If there's multiple `.Connect()` calls, then there will be multiple subscriptions, only one of which will be disposed. This could lead to leaks (don't know how EasyNetQ subscriptions are implemented).
- Best not to implement `IObservable` (or `IConnectableObservable`), because it's easy to make mistakes like the above.